# Cannot upload a file directly from local machine without using input type file elemnt in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I want to upload a image file from a jsp form to spring controller.
The problem is i do not want to browse the file using a `<input type="file"` tag because the image i'm getting from a webcam capture that is embeded in that jsp itself.
I am saving the webcam captured file into users local harddisk. now obviously user expects the form will be submitted(after filling all the fields)
along with the captured image without explicitly browsing the image again.

How to do that? how can i directly upload a file that is saved in the harddrive with the jsp form to Spring controller without using `<input type="file`" tag.
Also, is there any standard way to define users temp folder irrespective to the user?

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can't. If browsers allowed that, any web site could upload any file from your hard disk without you agreeing, or even noticing.

Comment: @JBNizet ok. Then can you advise how can i upload a webcam captured pic along with form data? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I have no idea how you can capture a webcam picture from a web page in the first place. But I guess that if you have access to the data and can save it to a local file, you should be able to easily send this data to the server using AJAX instead. What you can't do is save to a file, and then read that file.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah. After your first reply i was thinking so. Rather saving it to local, i would try to directly save it to server. Lets see.  Thank you very much for your help.